# WinGetPos() of Clipboard History

Tags: windows, autohotkey, clipboard

To implement a dynamic wait for the ***Windows Clipboard History***-Window (`Win`+`V`) via `PixelGetColor()` targeting the black frame (which I want to wait for), I'd need to determine the frame's position via `WinGetPos()`. `WinGetPos()`, however, needs ***WinTitle*** (ahk_class ahk_id ahk_pid ahk_exe etc.) on its part. So I spied the Windows Clipboard History-Window for this info, but the only thing unique about it is its "***All Text***"-field (`ahk_class` & `ahk_pid` are shared with e.g. Windows File Explorer and I think they also  at each new Windows ).

"***All Text***" can be retrieved via `WinGetText()`, but only if you know its ***WinTitle*** and as discussed I don't.

The best I could do to get Windows Clipboard History's ***All Text*** (***"CoreInput"***) and even its ***X*** and ***Y*** coordinates (which I'm after) was to hover over it with script ❶ active (which shows that yellow ToolTip on below Screenshot on the right side):

[image]

AHK Script ❶:

```
#Persistent
     SetTimer, WatchCursor, 100
return

WatchCursor:
     MouseGetPos, WindowRelX, WindowRelY, id, control
     WinGetTitle, outTitle, ahk_id %id%
     WinGetText, WinText, ahk_id %id%
     WinGetPos , WinPosX, WinPosY, WinPosWidth, WinPosHeight, ahk_id %id%
     WinGetClass, class, ahk_id %id%
     PixelGetColor, OutColor, WindowRelX, WindowRelY
     ToolTip, ahk_id %id%`nahk_class %class%`n%outTitle%`nControl: %control%`nOutColor: %OutColor%`nlast_active_window: %last_active_window%`nWindowRelX: %WindowRelX%`nWinPosX: %WinPosX%`nWindowRelY: %WindowRelY%`nWinPosY: %WinPosY%`nWinPosWidth: %WinPosWidth%`nWinPosHeight: %WinPosHeight%`nWinText: %WinText%`n
return
```

But I need to get Windows Clipboard History's ***X*** and ***Y*** coordinates *without* the mouse. So I thought I'll simply loop through *all* Windows and compare their text against Window Spy's *CoreInput* with script ❷, but it didn't yield anything:

AHK Script ❷:

```
Sleep, 5000
; in the meantime open Windows Clipboard History via Win+V
DetectHiddenWindows, On
WinGet, id, List,,, Program Manager
Loop, %id%
{
    this_id := id%A_Index%
    WinGetText, this_text, ahk_id %this_id%
    if (Trim(this_text) == CoreInput){
    Tooltip, %A_Index% of %id%`n`n`n%this_text%
    }
}
```

So how else can I get Windows Clipboard History's ***X*** & ***Y coordinates*** without the mouse, or more generally speaking implement a dynamic wait for Windows Clipboard History to be actually ready to receive keystrokes (like the `{Down}`-key)?

Comment: If all you're trying to do, is to create some script to manually macro the usage of the clipboard history dialog, I beg of you to go with a different approach. Honestly said, this would be so stupid since you can already access `ClipboardAll` and can subscribe to clipboard changes so easily with AHK. But if you're trying to achieve something different, I wonder what it is?

Comment: If it's so easy, then this will be easy 15 points for you. I will accept your answer of any kind as the solution if it 1. keeps track of the last say 8 clipboard items 2. of any data format that Windows Clipboard History accepts 3. OnClipboardChange 4. without deranging the order of the last 8 items in the process 5. without using Send because it's slow and only for text 6. the most recent cliboard element should be available for paste via a hotkey including 1 and the oldest one including 8. CAN YOU DO THAT?

Comment: ... 9. preferrably without creating any helper files or in any case no more than 8. CAN YOU DO THAT?

Comment: I tried to read your description from this comment, but it's really just way too confusing. Also, I don't really have time/motivation for a code writing service right now. If you want to try it yourself, I can look at it if you come across some issues.